# How to access this children div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to know how to use access this inside contents.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="more">more</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="more">more</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="more">more</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content .more{
    background:#009474;
    display:block;
    width:70px;
    height:25px;
}
.content:hover{
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 2s, 1s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    background:#009474;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".content").hover(function(){
    $(".content .more").css("background-color", "#D0D0D0");
  },function(){
  $(".content .more").css("background-color","#009474");
});
```

My aim is on hover that content should change to #009474 color, and inside class "more" color to some other. With this code on hover all other class "more" are changing. So what can i do to have only inside class to change color on hover.
Is $(this '.more') right to use but I am getting no change with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".content").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".more").css("background-color", "#D0D0D0");
  }
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks it start working now... I tried $(this).children(".more").. still was not working... but you code worked for me... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".content").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".more").css("background-color", "#D0D0D0");
  },function(){
   $(this).children(".more").css("background-color","#009474");
});

});
```

here is the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/4nxr9/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Javascript for that, CSS is sufficient:

```
.content:hover {
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 2s, 1s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    background:#009474;
}

/* .more child of the hovered .content */
.content:hover > .more {
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 2s, 1s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    background: #D0D0D0;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ngruk/).

If you want to achieve the same with JQuery, you have to [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (if it is a descendant) or [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (if it is a child) `.more` from the hovered `.content`:

```
$(".content").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".more").css("background-color", "#D0D0D0");
  }, function(){
    $(this).find(".more").css("background-color","#009474");
});
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2uGjW/1/) an example but CSS is the way, it is bad to mix style and code.